# Cannot reduce frame title height

Tags: beamer

I have an issue here with reducing the frame title height.

I tried several suggested solution but not all seem to work. I think the reason is I use `\useoutertheme{sidebar}`. I want to ask if there is any solution to adjust text size and frame height (the yellow frame title is too large; I want to make it smaller)?

```
\£documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


%\metroset{background=dark}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}


% Title Page
\title{Corporate Finance Chapter 03}
\subtitle{Class 01}
\author[]{Quoc T. Phan \\ Certified FRM - PhD. Candidate in Finance}
\institute{Department of Accounting Finance \\
            Asper School of Business \\
            University of Manitoba}
\date{2021-Jul}




\begin{document}

% TITLE PAGE
\begin{frame}{} %This should be empty otherwise there will be FRAME TITLE on TOP LEFT CORNER
\titlepage %This will give the 1st intro page
\end{frame}


% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}


\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{FRAME TITLE 01-01}
    Section 01 Slide 01
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{FRAME TITLE 01-02}
    Section 01 Slide 02
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The relevant length here seems to be `\beamer@headheight`, so you could use

```
\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=<length>
\makeatother
```

with a `<length>` of oyur choice to alter the height of the yellow box.

With `<length>` = `0.8cm`, you for example end up with the following output:

[image]

If you additionally want to decrease the font size of the frame titles, you might be interested in using

```
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=<size>}
```

with a `<size>` of your choice, such as `\large`, `\normalsize`, ... (For comparison: the default is `\Large`)

Comment: Thank you so much, it is perfect <3